# Decimal Field Validation in Textbox with Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I searched on the forum but didn't find the correct answer.
What I am trying is

1. Textbox which accepts decimal numbers, so user should be able
   to enter either 0 or 1 decimal point ie. dot(.)
2. at the max 5 digits before the dot and at the max 5 digits after the dot
3. no other character should be allowed, but arrow keys and other keys like f1 f2 should work

eg. it should be valid for following 
12345
12345.1
12345.12345
1.12345
.12345

Need help in making this textbox.

Comment: Try http://bit.ly/TNNi7s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function isFloat(s) {
    return s ? /\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,5})?/.test(s) : true;
}


$('input.float').on('change', function() {
  if (!isFloat($(this).val())) {
    alert('not a float');
  }
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/Vabj4/

The code doesn't make the field required. If it's empty, it'll just pass. If you can change that by changing `true` in the ternary conditional to `false` (line 2).

EDIT:

Oh, and if you want to restrict input to certain keys, you should reconsider. It's not a very good user experience. People are used to typing just about anything. It's best to just warn them. It's cheaper to do and it's effective enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/Vabj4/1/